# Issue with getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment

Tags: android

I am developing an android application and I want to save my fragment that is in the vector fragments. When I use putFragment in onSaveIstanceState the system throw IllegalStateException

```
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        // Salviamo lo stato 


        //salvo all fragment
        for(int i=0;i<fragments.size();i++)
            getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, Integer.toString(i), fragments.get(i));

    }
```

This is the logcat :

```
09-13 10:38:10.230: E/AndroidRuntime(24089): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment GenericPageFragment{417716e0} is not currently in the FragmentManager
09-13 10:38:10.230: E/AndroidRuntime(24089):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.putFragment(FragmentManager.java:516)
09-13 10:38:10.230: E/AndroidRuntime(24089):    at it.intects.dashboard.droid.BaseActivity.onSaveInstanceState(BaseActivity.java:180)
09-13 10:38:10.230: E/AndroidRuntime(24089):    at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1113)
09-13 10:38:10.230: E/AndroidRuntime(24089):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1188)
```

Why ? How can I resolve this error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do any fragment transactions after savedInstanceState() was called.

The activity will restore the last attached fragment when the activity returns.

And if you want to do any actions with fragments use:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.layout.container,new MyFragment(), "fragment_tag").commit();
```

[A very good tutorial about fragments](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sCQ8EcM0HM0)

Comment: but i put the fragment in fragmentpagerAdapter and use it in pageviewer

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html

Comment: can you be a little more specific? I had the same code than the OP and I don't see how this can help.

Comment: @astinx as I see now my answer was partially wrong, when your activity returns(onCreate() is called) just try use findFragmentByTag() or findFragmentById and see if the result is not null, if it is not null then your current fragment has been restored.