# Fragment is not currently in the FragmentManager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I searched on others similar posts but i didn't find a solution for my problem.

I'm using a library for a sliding menu (i know there exist an "official solution" now to do that but whatever)
So i've got this FragmentChangeActivity :

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // set the Above View
    if (savedInstanceState != null)
        mContent = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, "mContent");
    if (mContent == null)
        mContent = new AccueilFragment();   

    // set the Above View
    setContentView(R.layout.content_frame);
    getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.content_frame, mContent)
    .commit();

    // set the Behind View
    setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);
    getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.menu_frame, new AppliMenuFragment())
    .commit();

    // customize the SlidingMenu
    getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "mContent", mContent);
}

public void switchContent(Fragment fragment) {
    mContent = fragment;
    String tag = null;
    getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
    .addToBackStack(tag)
    .commit();
    getSlidingMenu().showContent();
}
```

From there, it will replace, on item click in the menu, each fragment by another. It works fine. The issue is, for example:

- Fragment A to -> Fragment B
- From the Fragment B i click the back button
- I'm again on Fragment A and i press home button

Here i've got this exception :

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment FragmentA is not currently in the FragmentManager

I found the problem there is where the code below is execute :

```
getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "mContent", mContent);
```

But i can't figure out why. Any Help would much apreciate !

**----- EDIT -----**

This is happening only when i press the back button then home button. In case where i juste press home button, getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment, work juste fine.

I understand that i can't do any fragment transactions after savedInstanceState() was called but getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment() isn't a transaction right? Or i miss something ? I'm not totally comfortable with that.

**----- SOLUTION -----**

I still don't understand why getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment() its not possible but from there, i removed it and use findFragmentByTag in onCreate :
        if (savedInstanceState != null)
            mContent = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("customtag");
        if (mContent == null)
            mContent = new AccueilFragment();
It have exactly the same behavior, keep the state when rotating and no more exception whe, i press back then home.

Answer (score 1):

i got this from here :[Issue with getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402562/issue-with-getsupportfragmentmanager-putfragment)

you cant make fragments transactions after onSaveInstanceState

Comment: Ok thanks for the link but how i can fix this ?i can't remove this code line because i need her when rotating.